# CSS Font-Family Appears Different On Iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari

I have a funky css issue specifically, the font-family. I'm using BrandonTextWeb-Regular.

On the chrome inspector - toggle device to the IPhone 6 plus, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W81TK.jpg

But for some strange reason on the IPhone itself it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlBXR.jpg on both the safari and chrome browser.

At first I thought the font-family was not being loaded on the device, but when I applied it, there was no change so I'm assuming it is loaded and it just looks different on the IPhone device? Is that possible?

On the android phone (S4, chrome browser) it looks like it suppose to be (first image).
 So it seem to be only the Iphone.

I also check it out on the Mac Safari and the font is fine as well. So it doesn't seem to be a browser issue.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's the CSS code that should be implementing this:

`body 
{
    font-family: BrandonTextWeb-Regular;
}`

Everything should be BrandTextWeb-Regular/Bold/Italic by default.

Comment: try posting your code that you are using to implement the font

Comment: @imvain2 added the code